# Generating unique combinations from a nested array (JS)

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, combinations

I'm trying to generate unique combinations from an array of arrays in Javascript.

```
Input: [ [1,1,3], [3,1,1], [4,4,4] ]
Output: [ [1,1,3], [4,4,4] ]
```

In this example, `[3,1,1]` is a duplicate of `[1,1,3]`. Adding the numbers to a Set doesn't seem to resolve the issue of duplicate arrays, and hashing the sorted, stringified array seems like a hack.

Edit: looking for a solution not involving stringified arrays, if it exists.

Is there a better way to solve this?

Comment: Are you just looking for unique arrays or also combinations of those arrays - e.g. power set?

Comment: Just the combinations, so we'd drop arrays with the same numbers in different orders.

Comment: It would seem that you are going to have to write a little program to do that. Start off by writing down what needs to be done in English, including how you plan to compare arrays with elements in different order. Then, write that as a JavaScript program.

Comment: Are the arrays always arrays of numbers or other primitive values only?

Comment: Yes, just ints.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a set with a sorted stringed array and filter accordingly.

```js
var array = [[1, 1, 3], [3, 1, 1], [4, 4, 4]],
    unique = array.filter(
        (s => a => (p => !s.has(p) && s.add(p))(a.slice().sort((a, b) => a - b).join()))(new Set)
    );

console.log(unique);
```

A slightly different approach without stringified arrays, but with a nested hash table which uses the length as first key.

```js
var array = [[1, 1, 3], [3, 1, 1], [4, 4, 4]],
    unique = array.filter(function (hash) {
        return function (a) {
            var found = true;
    
            a   .slice()
                .sort(function (a, b) { return a - b; })
                .reduce(function (r, k) {
                    found = found && r[k];
                    return r[k] = r[k] || {};
                }, hash[a.length] = hash[a.length] || {});
            return !found;
        };
    }(Object.create(null)));

console.log(unique);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Mapping arrays to primitive hash values allows to efficiently identify duplicates - in your case permutations.

A simple hash function is given by sorting the array and joining or stringifying it, which you prefer to avoid.

For integer arrays with limited range, you could map each integer n to the n-th prime number. The product of those prime factors is your hash. Since a product can be computed in linear time, this is faster than sorting at the cost of having to store a possibly large array of primes:

```js
const primes = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61];

function hash(numbers) {
  return numbers.reduce((prod, n) => prod * primes[n], 1);
}

function unique(arrays) {
  let set = new Set();
  return arrays.filter(numbers => {
    let h = hash(numbers);
    return !set.has(h) && set.add(h);
  });
}

console.log(unique([[1,1,3], [3,1,1], [4,4,4]]));
```

Comment: What the difference in run time complexity between your use of Map and Nina's Set?

Comment: Hi @Arrow, there is no difference in runtime complexity, but on second thought I'd rather go with a `Set` as the `Map.values()` iterator doesn't make much sense here.

Answer (score 0):

```
var output=Object.keys(input.reduce((obj,el)=>(obj[el.sort().join()]=true,obj),{})).map(arr=>arr.split().map(e=>+e));
```

You could sort the arrays, so that they are equal, and use a hash table to make the whole thing unique.

Comment: Nice, you'd also need to map again to cast back to int. But this is the 'hashing the sorted, stringified array' I'm trying to avoid.